# Java8 Lambda and Streams: <lambda parameter> instead of required

Tags: lambda, java-8, apache-poi

I have found a misunderstood using Java8 + Apache.POI:

1. I have a List `(itemList)`
2. Have a Sheet `(sheet)` and convert into stream of Row(s)
3. Filter Row(s) by: Boolean function(Row, Int) `(checkSap(row, importProperties.getSapIndex())`
4. ForEach Row(s) by: List.add(ListElement function(Row, ImpProp) `itemList.add(rowToItem(row2, impProp)`
5. Error: **Cannot resolve method forEach(< lambda expression >)** and highlighted `row2`

Do you know how can I solve it?

---

A piece of code:

```
    List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    StreamSupport.stream(sheet.spliterator(), false)
            .filter(row -> checkSap(row, importProperties.getSapIndex())
            .forEach(row2 -> {
                itemList.add(rowToItem(row2, impProp));
            });
```

RowToItem function:

```
private Item rowToItem(XSSFRow row, ImportProperties importProperties) {
    Item item = new Item();
    item.setSap(getString(row, importProperties.getSapIndex()));
    return item;
}
```

ImpProp class:

```
public class ImpProp{
    private String sapText;
    private Integer sapIndex;

    public boolean findSap(Row row) {
        Optional<Integer> optionalIndex = StreamSupport.stream(row.spliterator(), false)
            .filter(cell -> ((cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                    && (cell.getStringCellValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(sapText.trim()))))
            .findAny()
            .map(cell -> cell.getColumnIndex());

        if (optionalIndex.getClass().isInstance(Integer.class)) {
            sapIndex = optionalIndex.get();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Integer getSapIndex() {
        return sapIndex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you missing one of closing parenthesis? According to your code, you do.

```
StreamSupport.stream(sheet.spliterator(), false)
        .filter(row -> checkSap(row, importProperties.getSapIndex()))
        .forEach(row2 -> {
            itemList.add(rowToItem(row2, impProp));
        });
```

You should have three closing parenthesis on the line with filter. Otherwise `forEach` method will be applied to result of `checkSap` method.

Comment: Man! You are deadly right! Transposed digits. Thanks a lot for your investigate. :)